# Copying files from a network

Tags: python, windows

In this code I am trying to copy all files on a network that contain an keyword. Currently I am able to list/print all the files that contain the keyword but would like to copy them to a new location. So far I have been getting an error code 'IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '//server/Users$/' the other error codes listed are:

File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy

copyfile(src, dst)

File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile

with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

The weird thing is I am able to copy files, if I specify a user in the 'Users' directory. However, if I want to copy files that match my search from all users, I error out.

```
import os
import shutil


dest = '//server/user.name$/Copied_Files'
path = '//server/Users$/'
keyword = 'Keyword'

print 'Starting'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for name in files:
      if keyword in name.lower():
        shutil.copy(path, dest)

print 'Done'
```

Comment: Do you have $ sign in the actual folder ?

Comment: It's a hidden shared folder. should I exclude it?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the complete path when specifying the source. so  shutil.copy(path+name, dest). This worked for me.